# Cannot find libmysqlclient when compiling php5 on dreamhost

Tags: mysql, php

I'm trying to compile php5 on dreamhost, after doing what http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Installing_PHP5 said, I had compiled all the components except php5 itself. When running

```
$ ./configure ${PHPFEATURES}
```

It reported error

```
configure: error: Cannot find libmysqlclient under /usr.
Note that the MySQL client library is not bundled anymore!
```

But actually I find that /usr/lib64/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0 exists. How to help configure find it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try give different path for mysql, ie:

--with-mysql=/usr/lib64

m

Comment: I have modified the line to  --with-mysql=/usr/lib64, but the error still exists, and it still tries to find the file under /usr not /usr/lib64

Answer (score 1):

The MysqL installation includes a script called mysql_config, best is to point the compiler flags to this so the build system uses the compiler/linker flags provided by the installation.

```
--with-mysql=/path/to/bin/mysql_config
```

When using PHP 5.3 you could also use "myslqnd" as a path which would enable the "MySQL native driver" which is a PHP-specific replacement for the MySQL Client library and is independent from any libmysql.